# Does fetchrow_hashref return into a default value?

Tags: perl, default, dbi

I'm trying to write like:

```
my $q='select name as N from names';
my $sth=$dbh->prepare( $q ) ;
$sth->execute;
$test->{ $_->{N} } = 1 while $sth->fetchrow_hashref();
```

but $_ is undef. Does the return value get stored somewhere accessible without explicitly assigning it? Tim, it sure would be handy if it got stored somewhere!

Answer (score 4):

The `while` loop does not always implicitly assign a value to the default operator `$_`. As described in [perldoc perlsyn](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Compound-Statements):

> If the condition expression of a while statement is based on any of a
> group of iterative expression types then it gets some magic treatment.
> The affected iterative expression types are readline, the 
> input operator, readdir, glob, the  globbing operator, and
> each. If the condition expression is one of these expression types,
> then the value yielded by the iterative operator will be implicitly
> assigned to $_.

(...and otherwise it is not, is implied here)

To do what you want, you need to do

```
... while $_ = $sth->fetchrow_hashref();
```

Or better yet, use the idiomatic syntax:

```
while (my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
    $test->{ $row->{N} } = 1;
}
```

Comment: no- I didn't mean to imply the whlle loaded $_. I meant does the RV from fetchrow_hashref() land somewhere? With the plethora of perlvars, I'd hoped Tim snuck it in somewhere... So I might be able to do $test->{ $TIMS_SCRATCHPAD->{N} } = 1

Comment: @MiltonEarnestZilmer No. If it were to be stored anywhere it would be `$_`. There is no special default variable for `while` loops, that would be silly. It simply checks the truthyness of the function call and discards the return value.

Comment: And also, what would be the point of having some secret, hidden variable to access, when you know how to access the variable directly? Your question makes no sense to me. It is possible that it exists somewhere inside some DBI object that you created.